# Sum of this converging infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I would like to find the converging value of this expression:

$$z = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^s\mu_{x_j}^2}{\frac{1}{(1-\rho^2) \sigma^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^s\mu_{x_i}^2\mu_{y_j}^2 - \frac{\rho^2 (1 - \rho^2)}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^s \mu_{x_i}\mu_{y_i}\mu_{x_j}\mu_{y_j}},$$

as $s\rightarrow\infty$ (infinite series) and where,

$$\mu_{x_j} = \text{dx} \left(((j-1) \bmod n)+\frac{1}{2} (1-n)\right),$$
$$\mu_{y_j} = \text{dy} \left(\left\lceil \frac{j}{n}\right\rceil -\frac{n+1}{2}\right),$$

with all other variables being real. A plot of it in `Mathematica` shows a limiting values but I would like to find it analytically.

Comment: Why? In other words where does this come from?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, it is analytic result of a calculation. Plotting it shows a convergence of $z$ with large $s$. I would like to plot this convergence too.

Comment: It would be better to ask about the convergence of the *sequence* $z_s$, because the involved series seem not to converge.

Comment: @M.Winter, could you explain please?

Comment: @Sid It seems $|\mu_{x_j}|\ge \mathrm{dx}/2$ and $|\mu_{y_j}|\ge\mathrm{dy}/2$ (if not zero). A series $\sum a_i$ can only converge if $a_i\to 0$. This is no rigorous comment, just some feeling I got about your sums.